# Export Sharepoint Site to static HTML

Tags: 2010, 2013, html

I want to export a Sharepoint Site to static HTML. Is there an easy way to do it or a Tool which scrapes the content and exports the whole thing to HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

You can search for a tool that can automatically crawl and download all content, convert into html and package it.

Search for keyword like "website replica", "website archive", "website download manager" etc.